# Call a particular function of Class based view Django from urls.py

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I have this views.py where I've implemented Class based views, but let's say I want to call a function `get_featured_products` when the url is `https://localhost:8000/featured_products`. What sould my urls.py look like to call the `get_features_products` function?

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from rest_framework import views
from rest_framework.response import Response
from .models import * 
from .serializers import * 

# Create your views here.


class ProductView(views.APIView):
    model= Product
    serializer = ProductSerializer


    def get(self,request):
        qs = self.model.objects.all()
        serializer = self.serializer(qs, many=True)

        return Response(serializer.data)

    
    def post(self,request):
        serializer = self.serializer(data=request.data)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()
            return Response(serializer.data)

        return Response(serializer.error_messages())


    def put(self,request,pk):
        product = Product.objects.get(id=pk)
        serializer = self.serializer(instance=product, data=request.data)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()
            return Response(serializer.data)
        return Response(serializer.error_messages)

   def get_featured_products(self,request):
        #some code here
        return None
```

How should I refer to `get_featured_products` in my `urls.py`

Comment: Make a different view for that, or add a get / post parameter according to which you will return featured products

Comment: hi did you find a way?

Answer (score 1):

You can make the method as static and refer to this method from urls.py as:

```
# views.py
class ProductView(views.APIView):

    @staticmethod
    def get_featured_products(request):
        #some code here
        return None
        

# urls.py        
urlpatterns = [
    path('featured_products', ProductView.get_featured_products)
]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can list it as any other class-based view in your `urls.py` using `.as_view()` but you will always have to have `queryset` as a class variable in your class that inherits from `views.APIView`.

Your view has to be defined like this

```
class ProductView(APIView):
    queryset = Product.objects.all() # Here put your own queryset, for me if I dont i get error

    def get(self, request):
        print("GET REQUEST")
        return Response({"hello" : "world"})
    
    # you can similarly define other methods such as post, put like you already have
```

And then in your `urls.py`

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    # You'll obviously have to import it if it is not  in the same file
    path('featured_products', ProductView.as_view()) 
]
```

Answer (score 0):

For any class-based view, the urls.py can only contain ProductView.as_view(). It is not possible to directly refer to a method within a class.

as_view() function calls an instance of the class and returns a response based on the following methods:'get', 'post', 'put', 'patch', 'delete', 'head', 'options', 'trace'

If your method doesn't match the above, as is the case, you will get a HTTPresponseNotAllowed error.

You may place the method within one of the allowed methods and make it run.

You may check this link to know more: https://djangodeconstructed.com/2020/01/03/mental-models-for-class-based-views/