# Django module 'home.views' has no attribute 'IndexView'

Tags: django

I am a Django beginner going through a tutorial, I broke my site. It was working but now it's not and I have no idea what I've done wrong.

My app returns an error message:

[image]

My `urls.py` file looks like this:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import include,path
from django.views.generic import TemplateView

urlpatterns = [
    path('', include('home.urls')),
    path('polls/', include('polls.urls')),
    path('hello/', include('hello.urls')),
    path('home/', include('home.urls')),
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
]
```

Specifically `path('', include('home.urls')),` strikes me as the line of code of interest.  Therefore I look in my `home/urls.py` and see the following:

```
from django.urls import path

from . import views

app_name = 'home'
urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.IndexView.as_view(), name='index')
]
```

I changed the code above to the following:

```
from django.urls import path

from . import views

app_name = 'home'
urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.IndexView.as_view(), name='IndexView'),
    path('', views.IndexView.as_view(), name='index')
]
```

But get the same error.

Comment: Can you share the views.py code

Comment: Well it appears that your `views` has no `IndexView`.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem - You are nearly correct, I just looked and I don't have a `views` file!  Clearly that must be the issue. TY

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in your view.py file. Please check your view.py file

if your view.py is based on class follow this  "https://stackoverflow.com/a/74119291/20270008"

otherwise, you can directly call your views

like this

```html
  
#view.py 
def get_featured_products(request):
        #some code here
        return None

#url.py 
from how_to_post import views
urlpatterns = [
   
    path('/', views.get_featured_products),
]
```